# Cloth Wont Stay Attached to Character

Tags: rigging

I am trying to make a wing suit character but I cant get my cloth to attach properly to the character. I am using a child of constraint to attach the cloth the  bones but if I move the arm it wont still stay attached to the leg and if I move the leg it wont stay attached to the arm.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use a stretch to constraint, pointing from the foot to the hand bone.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to parent the cloth to the armature, then specify which part are deformed by which bones (it's called *skinning*).

Select your cloth, keep Shift pressed, select your armature, press Crtl+P. In the menu that opens, choose "With Empty Groups".

Select your cloth. In the Data panel, in "Vertex groups", you now have a list of groups, named after your bones. In Edit mode, select the vertex that needs to be attached to the leg, select the group named "shin.R", and click Assign. Do the same for the vertices that needs to be attached to the arm, this time select the group "forearm.R".